# Bootstrap Tags Input how to bind function to event itemAdded and itemRemoved?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-tags-input

There is no documentation about events on the website, any ideas ?http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

Comment: For anyone interested, this is fully documented now: https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Maybe the author have not had the time to document it yet? :-) But, bootstrap-tags triggers two signifcant events : `itemAdded` and `itemRemoved`.

Here is an example you can try out :

markup :

```html
<input type="text" value="Amsterdam,Washington,Sydney,Beijing,Cairo" data-role="tagsinput" placeholder="Add tags" id="tag"/>
```

event listeners :

```js
$("#tag").on('itemAdded', function(event) {
    console.log('item added : '+event.item);
});
$("#tag").on('itemRemoved', function(event) {
    console.log('item removed : '+event.item);
});
```

Here you go on your question.

Comment: @unclesol, investigate the code, it is not so complicated, my answer should not be there in the first place ...

Comment: Works for me :)

Comment: Great!. Works WELL